# Which event is fired after the data is loaded into datagrid or combobox?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Which event is fired after the data is loaded into datagrid or combobox ? (Assuming the dataprovider is set to the datagrid). Please Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "collectionChange" event is dispatched from ComboBase and ListBase, the base classes for ComboBox and DataGrid.

```
var event:CollectionEvent = new CollectionEvent(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE);
event.kind = CollectionEventKind.RESET;
...
dispatchEvent(event);
```